# glGetError() return GL_NO_ERROR, how correct is my code?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

My code is working 100% as expected and `glGetError()` always returns `GL_NO_ERROR`. Does this mean I'm doing everything correctly so far, or is it possible that there are errors in my code? As a test, I have introduced some errors in order to confirm that `glGetError()` works as expected, and it detects them. Generally speaking, though, are false negatives ever a thing when using `glGetError()`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by false negative?  Do you mean get an error code that wasn't thrown?  If so, I don't think OpenGL does something like that.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt An error that is not detected. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So `glGetError()` is designed to detect a list of errors right?  There are a very specific list of errors that it can return.  If an error that isn't in that wheelhouse is thrown, it would stand to reason the method wouldn't capture it.  On the other hand, an error could lead to your program crashing or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C/C++ code has no errors:

```
int x = 5 + 12 * 2;
```

It is entirely valid by both the C and C++ standards, and the resulting value will be well-defined: 27.

However, if you meant that 5 should be added to 12 *before* multiplying by 2... the answer will be wrong. It's still valid and well-defined, but it's not what you meant.

An OpenGL error can only gauge correctness from the perspective of the OpenGL specification. There is still plenty of opportunity for you to ask OpenGL to do one thing when you *meant* to do another.

Similarly, the following C/C++ code may or may not be valid:

```
void foo(int *ptr)
{
  *ptr += 5;
}
```

The compiler will compile this code completely without errors. But if you call this function with a NULL pointer, you get "undefined behavior". By doing `*ptr`, you promised the compiler that the pointer would not be NULL.

You also promised the compiler that the pointer would point to an object of type `int`, so if you call this function with a `float*` pointer that you cast into an `int*`, you also get undefined behavior.

OpenGL has similar places, where you promise OpenGL that you'll follow rules that the API *will not* check for, and if you break them, then bad things can happen. Reading from a texture while rendering to it is one case of UB, as is reading vertex data past the end of one of its buffer objects. There are *many* others.

If you get `GL_NO_ERROR`, that means that none of the errors that the specification explicitly detects for have happen. This doesn't mean your code does what you expect it to, nor does it mean your code will function reasonably.